# How to remove trailing slash in the URL for API created using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a django web-app and created rest apis for the same.
Here is the project structure

```
main_project
|
|___api
    |
    |___product
```

this is the `urls.py` in the main_project.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/v1/", include("api.urls"))
]
```

There is `urls.py` inside the api folder like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path("product/", include("api.product.urls"))]
```

Now inside the `product` folder I have created a `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("<str:id>", ProductView.as_view(), name="product")
]
```

Now when I run these apis on Postman I do get a trailing slash and the urls look like this
`localhost:8000/api/v1/product/xyz123`

also when I have to query something the urls look like this
`localhost:8000/api/v1/product/?sorting_field_name = product_name/`

Now as per the convention this is an incorrect way of naming urls, I want to remove those unnecessary trailing slashes.

How do I solve this?

Comment: remove the "api/v1/" pass it to the empty and then you can access like this 
ocalhost:8000/product/

Comment: In need to use ```api/v1/```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
`APPEND_SLASH = False`
in settings.py